# How to parametrize the surface $x^3 + 3xy + z^2 = 2$ and compute a tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametrization

How do I parametrize the surface $x^3 + 3xy + z^2 = 2$ and compute the tangent plane at $(1, \frac{1}{3}, 0)$ using the resulting parametrization?  I know that the tangent plane should be 
$$\nabla(x^3 + 3xy + z^2)\cdot(x - x_0, y - y_0, z - z_0) = 0 \implies \\
(3x_0^2 + 3y_0)(x - x_0) + 3x_0(y - y_0) + 2z_0(z - z_0) = 0,$$
which ends up being $4x + 3y = 5$ at $(1, \frac{1}{3}, 0)$.  However, the parametrization I thought was right did not give me this answer (I'm not ruling out the possibility that I did the gradient method wrong).

Comment: Solve the equation for one of the variables (there is a best choice) and use the other two variables to parametrize.

Comment: If you are referring to $z$ being the ideal variable, then you end up with a 0 in a denominator.  If you're referring to $y$, then this was when I got an equation for the tangent plane that didn't agree with the gradient one.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equation for $y$.
$$y=2/(3x) -(1/3)x^2 - (1/3)( z^2/x).$$

Let $u=x, z=v$.  Then $$y=(2/3)(1/u)-(1/3)u^2-(1/3)(v^2/u).$$
Hence the surface may be parameterized by:
$$F(u,v)=\left(u,\; (2/3)(1/u)-(1/3)u^2-(1/3)(v^2/u),\; v\right).$$
Compute tangent vectors of the parameterized surface
$$Tu=\langle 1,\;(-2/3u^2)-(2u)/3+(v^2)/(3u^2),\; 0\rangle$$  for $u=x=1$ and $v=z=0$. Then $$Tu=<1, -4/3, 0>$$

$$Tv=<0, -2v/3u, 1>$$  for u=x=1 and v=z=0.  Then   $$Tv=<0, 0, 1>$$
Find the cross-product Tu x Tv =...= <-4/3, -1, 0>  at (1, 1/3, 0)
equation of the tangent line will be:
(-4/3)(x-1)-1(x-1/3)+0(z-0)=0    .....
y=(-4/3)x+5/3

Comment: Please use ```\times```, ```\langle```, ```\rangle```, et cetera. More on MathJax is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack.